# TCP Socket receiving only a part of the message

Tags: sockets, tcp

I am using the following code to perform a tcp socket connection and send a string to an IP. But sometimes in the response,  I not receiving the entire file

```
     Socket m_socClient;
        IPSelected ="1.1.2.3"
                Port = "80"
                string query ="My Query"
                m_socClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                System.Net.IPAddress remoteIPAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(IPSelected);
                System.Net.IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(remoteIPAddress, Port);
                m_socClient.Connect(remoteEndPoint);
                try
                {
                    if (m_socClient.Connected)
                    {                       
                        var reQuestToSend = "";


                            reQuestToSend = string.Format("POST /TMHP/Request HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:{0}\r\nContent-Length:{1}\r\n\r\n{2}", "edi-webtest.tmhp.com", Query270.Length, Query270);
                        byte[] bytesToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reQuestToSend);
                        byteCount = m_socClient.Send(bytesToSend, SocketFlags.None);
                        byte[] bytesReceived = new byte[3000];
  byteCount = m_socClient.Receive(bytesReceived, SocketFlags.None);
                        Response271 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived);

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    EVCommon.Log(ex.Message);

                }
                finally
                {
                    m_socClient.Disconnect(false);
                    m_socClient.Close(5000);
                }
```

I think the problem is with     byte[] bytesReceived = new byte[3000];
Is there a way to not hardcode this number 3000. It works most of the time but for longer strings it gets only half of it.
I want it be handling variable sized messages instead of setting the byte size to  30000
Thank you

Comment: Where is the code that reads the socket? You'll have to keep reading until the server closes the connection, or you've received the last chunk, or read the bytes indicated by the Content-length header, or ... use an HTTP Library like WebClient or HttpClient.

Comment: I don't have access to the server code. I am sure they are receiving the entire string. Because until they receive a complete string which passes validation on their end, they do not respond with another string. The problem is not with reading. Its a problem with receiving the response

Comment: Like @CodeCaster says - where is the code to read from the socket into the bytesReceived array?

Comment: @MartinJames: oops sorry.. I accidentally removed that line. Edited post

Comment: Why aren't you using URL and URLConnection for this? They solve all this, and many other things besides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4).  It tells you how to determine the end of the server's response so you know how many bytes to read.  You have to read and process the server's response headers first in order to know how the remaining data, if any, is being transmitted.  Then you can keep reading from the socket accordingly, potentially parsing what you have read, until the end of the response has actually been reached.  Your current reading code is not even close to satisfying that requirement.

For example (pseudo code):

```
line = read a CRLF-delimited line;

responseNum = extract from line;
httpVer = extract from line;

do
{
    line = read a CRLF-delimited line;
    if (line == "") break;
    add line to headers list;
}
while (true);

if (((responseNum / 100) != 1) &&
    (responseNum != 204) &&
    (responseNum != 304) &&
    (request was not "HEAD"))
{
    if ((headers has "Transfer-Encoding") &&
        (headers["Transfer-Encoding"] != "identity"))
    {
        do
        {
            line = read a CRLF-delimited line;
            chunkLen = extract from line, decode hex value;
            if (chunkLen == 0) break;
            read exactly chunkLen number of bytes;
            read and discard a CRLF-delimited line;
        }
        while (true);

        do
        {
            line = read a CRLF-delimited line;
            if (line == "") break;
            add line to headers list, overwrite if exists;
        }
        while (true);

        decode/transform read data based on headers["Transfer-Encoding"] values if more than just "chunked"
    }
    else if (headers has "Content-Length")
    {
        read exactly headers["Content-Length"] number of bytes
    }
    else if (headers["Content-Type"] == multipart/byteranges)
    {
        boundary = headers["Content-Type"]["boundary"];
        read and parse MIME encoded data until "--"+boundary+"--" line is reached;
    }
    else
    {
        read until disconnected;
    }
}

if (((httpVer >= 1.1) && (headers["Connection"] == "close)) ||
    ((httpVer < 1.1) && (headers["Connection"] != "keep-alive")))
{
    disconnect;
}
```

I leave it as an exercise for you to actually implement this in your code.

Comment: You've *got* examples. You've got the request you're trying to send, and the response you're trying to read.

Comment: I could try and implement it.. But out of 500 or 1000 transactions per day, I get this problem in less tha 5 requests. So 95% or more are successful.

Comment: But there are basic problems even with the code you have shown. You have been lucky so far that it works at all, let alone 95% of the time. You are not formatting/sending the request how it should be handled, and you have to implement the algorithm I outlined to get the response correctly. That is how HTTP works. You really should use a pre-made HTTP API/library instead of trying to implement HTTP manually.